# Devtools - How to calculate the memory consumaption of every library

Tags: node.js, memory, google-chrome-devtools, profiler

I'm trying to debug high memory consumpation of my NodeJs (v14.15.4) service and I have noticed that ***just by*** importing `nest-winston` (without using any of it's functiollity), the memory consumpation is increased by 20mb in the RSS:

- With `import { WINSTON_MODULE_PROVIDER } from 'nest-winston'`:

```
rss: 108 ,heapTotal: 57 ,heapUsed: 35 ,external: 31 ,arrayBuffers: 12
```

- Without `import { WINSTON_MODULE_PROVIDER } from 'nest-winston'`:

```
rss: 55 ,heapTotal: 13 ,heapUsed: 12 ,external: 18 ,arrayBuffers: 0
```

- Size in MB, calculated by `process.memoryUsage()`.

---

### Question

I don't want to test out every inner import of `nest-winston` (recorsively) until I understand what causes the problem. It may take alot of time.

How can I determine the memory consumpation of every library I imported using the Devtools?